# Zoom not launching Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.10, zoom-meeting

I am trying to install the Zoom desktop client on Ubuntu 22.10.

Ubuntu is up-to-date, and I have an RTX 4090 with proprietary drivers version 525.

Installing Zoom with `sudo apt install zoom_amd64.deb` succeeds, but upon opening the application, it fails to start and displays a transparent window.

I suspect it's related to my GPU since it's fairly new. Has anyone else faced this issue and found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just got a new laptop (Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 10) and slapped Ubuntu 22.10 on it.

For me Zoom starts, display the icon in the taskbar and quits.

Edit:

I was able to get it running by uninstalling the `deb` package and installing it via snap with `snap install zoom-client`